# How to make devtoolset g++ available for Makefile in docker's centos7?

Tags: centos, yum, docker, make, gcc

I am building a docker image from a basement image which installed the CentOS 7.

The code that need to be compiled need some features in C++14/17 standard, thus i have to update the default gcc/g++ version from 4.8.5 to a higher version.

I've read some post and article, do the following command to update the g++ in Dockerfile

```
RUN yum -y install centos-release-scl && \
yum -y install devtoolset-7-gcc* && \
source scl_source enable devtoolset-7 &&
g++ -version
```

It did print the right version.

> g++ (GCC) 7.3.1 20180303 (Red Hat 7.3.1-5)

However, when i build my code through make, it still use the old version, thus the build flag `-std=c++14` can not be recognized, to verify this, i append the version target to Makefile and run command in Dockerfile as follow.

Makefile:

```
# ...
CXX:=g++
FLAGS:=-Wall -fPIC -std=c++14
# ...
%.o: %.cpp
    $(CXX) $(FLAGS) -c $< -o $@ $(INCLUDE_PATH)
# ...
version:
    g++ -v
```

Dockerfile:

```
RUN cd /home/admin/${APP_NAME}/nginx-base/cplusplus && make version && make
```

With an output in docker build stage:

```
Using built-in specs.
COLLECT_GCC=g++
COLLECT_LTO_WRAPPER=/usr/libexec/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.8.5/lto-wrapper
Target: x86_64-redhat-linux
Configured with: ../configure --prefix=/usr --mandir=/usr/share/man --infodir=/usr/share/info --with-bugurl=http://bugzilla.redhat.com/bugzilla --enable-bootstrap --enable-shared --enable-threads=posix --enable-checking=release --with-system-zlib --enable-__cxa_atexit --disable-libunwind-exceptions --enable-gnu-unique-object --enable-linker-build-id --with-linker-hash-style=gnu --enable-languages=c,c++,objc,obj-c++,java,fortran,ada,go,lto --enable-plugin --enable-initfini-array --disable-libgcj --with-isl=/builddir/build/BUILD/gcc-4.8.5-20150702/obj-x86_64-redhat-linux/isl-install --with-cloog=/builddir/build/BUILD/gcc-4.8.5-20150702/obj-x86_64-redhat-linux/cloog-install --enable-gnu-indirect-function --with-tune=generic --with-arch_32=x86-64 --build=x86_64-redhat-linux
Thread model: posix
gcc version 4.8.5 20150623 (Red Hat 4.8.5-28) (GCC) 
g++ -Wall -fPIC -std=c++14 -c image_engine.cpp -o image_engine.o -I /opt/taobao/tengine/data/include
g++: error: unrecognized command line option '-std=c++14'
make: *** [image_engine.o] Error 1
The command '/bin/sh -c cd /home/admin/${APP_NAME}/nginx-base/cplusplus && make version && make' returned a non-zero code: 2
```

So how should i do to make g++-7 activated in my Makefile, instead of the default g++ of CentOS?

Comment: Does this work?  `RUN source scl_source enable devtoolset-7 && cd /home/admin/${APP_NAME}/nginx-base/cplusplus && make version && make`

Comment: @GracefulRestart It did work, thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the comments and my own experience with Docker, each `RUN` line is run in a separate shell environment, so when you source an environment in one `RUN` line, that environment is not available to other `RUN` commands.

Using the line `RUN source scl_source enable devtoolset-7 && cd /home/admin/${APP_NAME}/nginx-base/cplusplus && make version && make` instead of your previous `RUN` command makes sure the current environment is setup for the `make` command.

Answer (score 0):

As a workaround:

```
SHELL ["sh", "-c", "source scl_source enable $(scl -l) && sh -c \"$0\" \"$@\""]
```

it replaces the shell for all following RUN.